# KeyError: 'GroupName'

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm creating an IAM group and trying to print the group name that gets created. When I try that, it's giving me this error

```
KeyError: 'GroupName'
```

Here's my function

```
def cf_admin_iam_group():
iam = boto3.client('iam')

try:
    response = iam.create_group(GroupName='Test')
    print(response['GroupName'])
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
    print(error)
```

When I try to just `print(response)`

I get the expected output

```
{'Group': {'Path': '/', 'GroupName': 'Test', 'GroupId': 'AGPAXVCO7KXYHZP24FQFZ', 'Arn':
 'arn:aws:iam::526299125232:group/Test', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 13, 19, 17, 51, tzinfo=tzutc())}, 
'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '7b2e7c6c-a811-497a-b2c5-177c70a0464c', 
'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '7b2e7c6c-a811-497a-b2c5-177c70a0464c', 
'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '490', 'date': 'Tue, 13 Sep 2022 19:17:51 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

I'm not sure why running `print(response['GroupName'])` is giving me an error instead of printing the group name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` is a dictionary, and `GroupName` is a key of the `Group` value, so you need to use:

```
print(response['Group']['GroupName'])
```